# Check if two list of numbers are equal

Tags: algorithm

Given two lists A,B of numbers. Is there a better way to check if they are equal than an O(N^2) solution.

Comment: Define "equal". Same order? Duplicate elements?

Comment: Do you mean 'is there a better way to check if they contain the same numbers ?'  In my book list equality requires that the numbers be both the same and in the same order which I believe requires an O(n) operation to check.

Comment: Any special characteristics of the lists? Are they sorted? Are the numbers bounded? Also, are you allowed to use a non-constant amount of additional memory?

Answer (score 4):

Sort the 2 lists **O(nlogn)**
Then go over both of them simultaneously and see that they contain the same numbers **O(n)**

Total: **O(nlogn)**

Answer (score 1):

If you mean, that both lists contain the same numbers with no respect to the ordering, you can use the following `O( n *log n )` algorithm:

1. Sort both lists in the same way (e.g. ascending)
2. Compare the resulting lists item by item starting from top

Step (1) takes `2 * O( n *log n ) = O( n *log n )` time. The second step runs in linear `O(n)` time.

So running the above algorithm solves your problem in `O( n *log n )` time.

Comment: If numbers are integer, you can use Bucket Sort algorithm that has time complexity of O(n) (to be more precise, time complexity is O(n+r), with r the range of numbers), reducing the problem to O(n)+O(n)+O(n) = O(n) complexity

Comment: Or a binary radix sort for `O(n * log(r))`, with `r` this time being the maximum representable value rather than the max value actually present. It can be done in place, which is nice.

Answer (score 1):

First check if they are equal in length. If they are, you can put numbers of A in a HashSet. Iterate through B and check if it is there in HashSet. If it is there you can remove from HashSet. If in the end HashSet is empty they are equal. This is O(n)

Actually duplicates are not allowed in HashSet so you can have a HashMap with key as the number and value as count. The algorithm remains the same. Everytime a number of B is found in HashMap decrement count. If in the end HashMap is empty then they are equal. This is O(n) too.

Comment: Thanks. I too figured out O(n * logn) algo but i liked urs!!

Comment: Thanks. I like it too :). And it would help if you can accept (again only if you liked it :)) my answer especially because (surprisingly) no one's upvoted mine :).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the numbers are sorted on the list, and both lists have the same length:

```
bool eq = true;

for (int i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
    if (list1[i] != list2[i]) {
        eq = false;
        last;
    }
}
```